# Core Data: deleteObject crashes application, NSPredicate the cause?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using a UICollectionView along with Core Data.

I can't seem to figure out why I can't remove an object from Core Data. It crashes at `[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:animation];` with an `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array` error. The following method is a delegate method that gets invoked from another viewcontroller. It gets a timestamp NSInteger and should create an NSPredicate with that timestamp.

The strange thing is that when I take the animationTimestamp NSInteger and hardcode it like:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %i", @"1370169109"]` it works and the object gets deleted without the error. However, when I want to pass the parameter as the argument it crashes. I've tried making it a string, NSNumber etc. Nothing works when I take the parameter, it only does when I hardcode it. I've logged animationTimestamp and it shows the correct value, so I'm stuck.

Thanks!

```
- (void)deleteAnimationWithTimestamp:(NSInteger)animationTimestamp {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Animations" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %i", animationTimestamp];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *animations = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *animation in animations) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:animation];
    }

    // Save core data
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.animationsCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

EDIT:
More info that might matter. The timestamp attribute in the model is a 64 bit integer (should it be by the way?). When I create the object I use:

```
NSNumber *timestampNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp];
[newAnimation setValue:timestampNumber forKey:@"timestamp"];
```

Comment: Does your object have a relationship dependency to any other entity?

Comment: try to change from %i to %d in your predicate

Comment: @kushyar I only have one entity, Animations.

Comment: @verbumdei I've tried %i, %d, %@ already unfortunately.

Comment: What you are doing when you hard code the value is not the same thing when you don't hard code it. When you hard code the value you are sending a NSString as parameter and when you don't hardcode it you are sending a NSInteger. So as @verbumdei said, change the %i to %d

Comment: @danypata I've also tried making a string from the integer before I make the predicate with that string instead of the integer. That also didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: try this: `@"timestamp == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:animationTimestamp]`?

Comment: @verbumdei Same thing, that also crashes with the beyond bounds error. This works, bizarrely: `@"timestamp == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1370172306]`

Comment: something is wrong with your animationTimestamp then. Are you use it is NSInteger?

Comment: @verbumdei `[self.reviewAnimationViewDelegate deleteAnimationWithTimestamp:1370172306];` works, but `[self.reviewAnimationViewDelegate deleteAnimationWithTimestamp:self.animationTimeStamp];` doesn't. So you're probably right that there is something wrong with the timestamp NSInteger. `self.animationTimestamp` here is the NSInteger in the viewcontroller that calls the method on the delegate.

`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger animationTimestamp;` I set this integer where needed.

Comment: Try to log the self.animationTimestamp passed to the delegate or set a breakpoint and print the value, using po self.animationTimeStamp.

Comment: It logs okay right before I call the delegate method. It's why this is all very weird to me.

Comment: Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"predicate=%@", predicate)` for both the working and the non-working case?

Comment: @MartinR They both log `predicate=timestamp == 1370179632`. One crashes, the other doesn't. Does it have something to do with the fact that my delegate method is in a view controller a few down the navigation stack. I set the delegate by doing `setReviewAnimationViewDelegate:self.delegate`

Comment: @MartinvanderWoude: If the predicate and everything else is identical then I do not see why it should behave differently. - Perhaps set a "Breakpoint on all Objective-C Exceptions" and post the stack backtrace of the crash.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out the predicate stuff was a side effect, still a weird one I don't understand. But I was calling another delegate method a bit after the `deleteAnimationWithTimestamp:(NSInteger)animationTimestamp` where I was using another predicate. And because the object got deleted before that predicate could do anything with it I got an array beyond bounds error. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Get the NSInteger value from NSNumber 
Like

```
NSInteger timestampNumber = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:timestamp] integerValue];
// then use this integer 

[newAnimation setValue:timestampNumber forKey:@"timestamp"];

// or in 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %d", timestampNumber];
```